# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: user_name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This Code Gives Error While Extraction Data From  the Firebase Database
in the Line

`UsersForChat usersForChat = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersForChat.class);`
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: user_name

```
public class Users_Display_For_Chat_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    ArrayList<UsersForChat> users = new ArrayList<UsersForChat>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    UsersDispalyActivtyRecyclerViewAdapter rvadapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        rvadapter = new UsersDispalyActivtyRecyclerViewAdapter(this,users);



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_UsersForChat);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvadapter);

        retrivedata();
    }

    public void retrivedata()
    {
        databaseReference.child("Users").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                UsersForChat usersForChat = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersForChat.class);
                users.add(usersForChat);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the Pojo Class UsersForChat

```
public class UsersForChat {

    String User_Name,User_PhoneNo,User_Profile_Pic_Url;

    public UsersForChat()
    {

    }

    public UsersForChat(String User_Name, String User_PhoneNo, String User_Profile_Pic_Url) {
        this.User_Name = User_Name;
        this.User_PhoneNo = User_PhoneNo;
        this.User_Profile_Pic_Url = User_Profile_Pic_Url;
    }

    public String getUser_Name() {
        return User_Name;
    }

    public String getUser_PhoneNo() {
        return User_PhoneNo;
    }

    public String getUser_Profile_Pic_Url() {
        return User_Profile_Pic_Url;
    }

    public void setUser_Name(String user_Name) {
        User_Name = user_Name;
    }

    public void setUser_PhoneNo(String user_PhoneNo) {
        User_PhoneNo = user_PhoneNo;
    }

    public void setUser_Profile_Pic_Url(String user_Profile_Pic_Url) {
        User_Profile_Pic_Url = user_Profile_Pic_Url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are at the beginning of your project and you can make database changes, I recommend you changing all your field names, setters, and getters lower case according to [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Also, you need to change the visibility of all your fields from `default access` to `private access` like this:

```
private String userName, userPhoneNo, userProfilePicUrl;
```

And the setters and getters like this:

```
public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {this.userEmail = userEmail;}    
public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;}

public String getUserPhoneNo() {return userPhoneNo;}
public void setUserPhoneNo(String userPhoneNo) {this.userPhoneNo = userPhoneNo;}

public String getUserProfilePicUrl() {return userProfilePicUrl;}
public void setUserProfilePicUrl(String userProfilePicUrl) {this.userProfilePicUrl = userProfilePicUrl;}
```

As you probably see, only the setter, and getters have `public access`.

If you cannot change the names of the fields in your database then you need just to change the visibility of your fileds.

Comment: This won't work if the database field is named "user_name".  The Firebase SDK won't know how to map user_name to setUserName, without some additional clues about how to make that association.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I advised Sharad Dadhich to change the name of the fileds as above, according to [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: But it might be a royal pain to change the names of all the fields in the database, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would. You are right again Doug. Answer changed. Thank you again! ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you make a POJO, it's customary to make all the fields private in order to force access through only the getters and setters.

```
private String User_Name,User_PhoneNo,User_Profile_Pic_Url;
```

Also, traditionally, you don't use underscores in method names and members, just camel case.  But I suppose that's up to you.